# Resize pre element tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make my `<div>`dynamic so that its vertical height gets increase automatically.
Currently i am using `<textarea>`to define the content in it. But i want to replace it with `<pre>` to make it more effective.Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

`Code`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  textArea.addEventListener('change', autosize, false)
  textArea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize, false)
  textArea.addEventListener('keyup', autosize, false)
  autosize()
}, false)

function autosize() {
  textCopy.innerHTML = textArea.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
}
```

```css
html,
body,
textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
}

.textarea-container>div,
.textarea-container>textarea {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.textarea-container>textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.textarea-container>div {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
  <div id="textCopy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a contenteditable div: https://jsfiddle.net/rs93e6dL/

Comment: because i want to preserve white spaces and next line...

Comment: You can preserve white space and new lines: https://jsfiddle.net/f08r3upv/

Comment: *I am trying to make my <div>dynamic so that its vertical height gets increase automatically.*  That is the natural behaviour of the `div` element. Just don't ruin it.

Comment: @hev1 thanks for the solution but the problem is backspace is not working now. I can add the text cant delete it...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the height to the scroll size

```js
textArea.style.height = "23px";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  textArea.addEventListener('change', autosize, false)
  textArea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize, false)
  textArea.addEventListener('keyup', autosize, false)
}, false)

function autosize() {
  textArea.style.height = parseInt(textArea.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

```css
html,
body,
textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
}

.textarea-container>div,
.textarea-container>textarea {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.textarea-container>textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 23px;
}

.textarea-container>div {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
</div>
```